# How to normalize json file containing a list (that should be kept as a list) in Python | Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

I'm trying to use the json_normalize function to convert a json file into a dataframe.

### Source JSON

- The json is a list of dictionaries that look something like this:

  ```
  {
        "sport_key": "basketball_ncaab",
        "sport_nice": "NCAAB",
        "teams": [
            "Bryant Bulldogs",
            "Wagner Seahawks"
        ],
        "commence_time": 1608152400,
        "home_team": "Bryant Bulldogs",
        "sites": [
            {
                "site_key": "marathonbet",
                "site_nice": "Marathon Bet",
                "last_update": 1608156452,
                "odds": {
                    "h2h": [
                        1.28,
                        3.54
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "site_key": "sport888",
                "site_nice": "888sport",
                "last_update": 1608156452,
                "odds": {
                    "h2h": [
                        1.13,
                        5.8
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "site_key": "unibet",
                "site_nice": "Unibet",
                "last_update": 1608156434,
                "odds": {
                    "h2h": [
                        1.13,
                        5.8
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "sites_count": 3
    }
  ```

The problem is that one of the future columns contains a list (which should be the case), but including this column in the meta part of the json_normalize function throws the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (22,) (11,)
```

The error appears when I try to add "teams" in the list in the following code:

```
pd.json_normalize(data, 'sites', ['sport_key', 'sport_nice', 'home_team', 'teams'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `data` is a list of dictionaries, you can still use `json_normalize` but you have to assign the `teams` column seperately for each corresponding dictionary in `data`:

```
def normalize(d):
    return pd.json_normalize(d, 'sites', ['sport_key', 'sport_nice', 'home_team'])\
           .assign(teams=[d['teams']]*len(d['sites']))


df = pd.concat([normalize(d) for d in data], ignore_index=True)
```

Alternatively you can try:

```
data = [{**d, 'teams': ','.join(d['teams'])} for d in data]
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'sites', ['sport_key', 'sport_nice', 'home_team', 'teams'])
df['teams'] = df['teams'].str.split(',')
```

Result:

```
      site_key     site_nice  last_update      odds.h2h         sport_key sport_nice        home_team                               teams
0  marathonbet  Marathon Bet   1608156452  [1.28, 3.54]  basketball_ncaab      NCAAB  Bryant Bulldogs  [Bryant Bulldogs, Wagner Seahawks]
1     sport888      888sport   1608156452   [1.13, 5.8]  basketball_ncaab      NCAAB  Bryant Bulldogs  [Bryant Bulldogs, Wagner Seahawks]
2       unibet        Unibet   1608156434   [1.13, 5.8]  basketball_ncaab      NCAAB  Bryant Bulldogs  [Bryant Bulldogs, Wagner Seahawks]
```

Comment: Thanks, the second suggestion solved my problem!